Equivalence of Taylor Expansion and L'Hospital
Is the rule of L'Hospital equivalent to Taylor Expansion?:
A analytic (or for this sake one time differentiable) function $f(x)$ can be expanened around $x_0$ with
$f(x) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x-x_0) + O(x^2)$.
If $f(x_0)$ happens to be zero this can be used to evaluate a limit directly, but one could also use L'Hospital rule (if the conditions are met).
I believe most proofs of L'Hospital rule are like the following:
If $f(x_0) = g(x_0) = 0$, we can expand (!) the functions around their null points:
$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+O(x^2)}{g(x_0)+g'(x_0)(x-x_0)+O(x^2)}$
$=\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$
So now my simple question: Is L'Hospital simply a special case of the Taylor expansion (up to first order; and around a null point)?

Technically all you have used is the fact that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x_0$. The existence of a full Taylor series is not a requirement to use L'Hopital

I learned Taylor expansion (now just the polynomials not the series) as a expansion around $x_0$ for a $\mathcal{C}^n$ function up to order $O(x^n)$, in that sense the derivative is nothing but the first order /linear approximate of the function. My question is now, if L'Hospital uses "Taylor expansion" (already thinking of repeated application); or if there is really something more to this idea to calculate limits?

The idea behind l’hospital’s rule is: use local linear approximation on the numerator and the denominator, then simplify and l’hospital’s rule pops out. If you want to prove a version of l’hospital’s rule that uses minimal assumptions on $f$ and $g$ then the proof may get more complicated, but that is the basic idea.

What do you mean with minimal assumptions? And the linear approximation is just what I used in my calculation above.

But you also assumed that the difference between the function and the linear approximation was $O(x^2)$, when differentiability of $f$ at $x_0$ only provides us with $o(x)$ (that one is trivial, since you didn't use anything stronger than $o(x)$). But you also assumed that the derivatives are continuous at $x_0$ in your final step. L'Hospital does not require a continuous derivative. This is what "minimal assumptions" means.

Well, thanks for the comment. But my assumption of $O(x^2)$ was simply wrong wasn't it. A Taylor Expansion of a $n$-time differentiable function is just  $o(x^n)$, we simply use often the remainder formulas with $O(x^{n+1})$ for a $\mathcal{C}^(n+1)$ functions.  And my droping of the limit was also not necessary wasn't it. Can I write $lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x_0) + f'(x)(x-x_0)+o(x)}{g(x_0) + g'(x)(x-x_0)+o(x)}$ instead (maybe based on mean value theorem)?
